# Adding string to the end of submitted URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am putting together a simple tool for work where a user can add in some data to a form field which allows them to remotely access a device, but I need it to take them to the the login page.

```
<input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="http://" />
<a href="http://" onclick="this.href=document.getElementById('prog_site').value" target="_blank">Let's go!</a>
```

the above takes them to the said device, but I am having problems with adding a script that then adds on the following after the submitted info (which is an IP address)

/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/authForm.cgi

I have been looking at ways but need it to be as simple as possible?

Here is the full script:

```
    <script>
function open_win() 
{
window.open("");
}
</script>

<style>
body {
background-color: #fff;
}
</style>

<p><img src="logo.gif" /></p>

<p>Hello customer</p>

<p>Welcome to the Activation</p>

<p><a target="_new" href="">Instructions</a></p>


<input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="http://" />
<a href="http://" onclick="this.href=document.getElementById('prog_site').value" target="_blank">Let's go!</a>
```

Comment: Can you please give an example, I'm having problems understanding where and what you want to add

Comment: @Spokey I have edited my post so you see the full script. so in the input field a user would put in the IP address and select lets go and it will open a new tab going to that page. But I need it to add on the end of that this part to take them to the login page /web/guest/en/websys/webArch/authForm.cgi

Comment: `thevalue + thepath` should be enough. simple string manipulation.

Comment: @KevinB Mmm... poetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly I'm misreading the question, but what is wrong with:

```
<a href="http://"
    onclick="this.href=(document.getElementById('prog_site').value +
                       '/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/authForm.cgi')"
    target="_blank">Let's go!</a>
```

?

Comment: you sir have hit the nail on the head :)

Comment: I am just having an issue with IE and it wanting to enable cooking, but im guessing there is no way around that?

Comment: Maybe it's hungry? ;)

Comment: Haha okok this is serious :p

Comment: Ok, more seriously it sounds like you do have an issue outside the scope of this problem. Nothing in the solution here should be browser-specific, so it's more likely to be something connected with the coding of authForm.cgi.

Comment: Yeah i agree I was just discussing this with my colleague - i think maybe I need it to briefly land on the home page and then redirect to this login page...any ideas?

Comment: Again, this does depend on how authForm.cgi is written; without knowing more details of how that works I can't say whether or not that would solve you problem unfortunately. You may want to raise this as a new question where more information can be given, and opens it up to people with expertise in related areas.

Answer (score 0):

Your question not clear for me. But i think you want to add a `QueryString` into your URL.
So you can simply add this using `?` symbol.

```
var URL = "YourURL";
    URL = URL + "?IP=" + "YourString";
```

After Update -

```
<a href="http://" onclick="this.href=(document.getElementById('prog_site').value +'/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/authForm.cgi')" target="_blank">Let's go!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
<input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="http://" />
<a href="http://" onclick="this.href+=('/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/authForm.cgi?ip=' + document.getElementById('prog_site').value); return true;" target="_blank">Let's go!</a>
```

Comment: Almost! It comes up now with an error saying it could not find the specified path as if its looking locally for my input as saying C:// at the start of the error.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Kcqu/)

```
<input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="http://" />
<input type="button" value="Let's go!" onclick="window.location.replace('http://web/guest/en/websys/webArch/authForm.cgi?ip='+document.getElementById('prog_site').value); return true;"></input>
```