# Issues with loading page in IE asking to enable cookies

Tags: javascript, batch-file, cgi

I have a form which opens up a specific page in IE but it is a .cgi

/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/authForm.cgi

Please see this post:

[Adding string to the end of submitted URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725830/adding-string-to-the-end-of-submitted-url/17726048?noredirect=1#comment25839093_17726048)

```
<input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="http://" />
<a href="http://" onclick="this.href=document.getElementById('prog_site').value" target="_blank">Let's go!</a>
```

The above code is an input field which opens up a new tabs with the submitted URL and add on the file ext provided. But the page requires cookies to make it work.

Comment: And the problem is ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code only changes the `href` attribute when clicked, which is already too late.
Consider

```
<input type="text" name="prog_site" id="prog_site" value="http://" 
       onkeyup="document.getElementById('href_target').href=this.value" />
<a id="href_target" href="http://" target="_blank">Let's go!</a>
```

Comment: This just takes me to the homepage for some reason...I see what its trying to do though.

Comment: The only way I am able to get around this is by landing on the page and re launching it in a new window...

Comment: Still don't know what you're doing exactly :/